# Question is : Property 'switchMap' does not exist on type 'Observable<User>

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs6, switchmap

I have this problem when trying to run in git bash.
.switchMap is not geting executed  and showing error as" error TS2339: Property 'switchMap' does not exist on type 'Observable' "

The code I am using is:

```
import { User } from './../classes/user';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  public currentUser: Observable<User | null>;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private alertService: AlertService,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private db: AngularFirestore
  ) {

    this.currentUser = this.afAuth.authState
      .switchMap((user) => {
        if (user) {
          return this.db.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      });
  }
```

my rxjs version is rxjs@6.3.3  latest and nodejs version is v8.12.0
please help I am building a chat website.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that in RxJs 6 the `switchMap` (along with many other operators) no longer exists on the Observable. Instead you have to pipe the observable using the `.pipe()` operator which takes any amount of methods and applies them to the observable. You then import the `switchMap` function to use it in the pipe..

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

....

this.currentUser = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
  switchMap((user) => {
    if (user) {
      return this.db.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
    } else {
      return of(null);
    })
);
```

If you're used to the old (RxJs 5) behaviour and you would like to work that way there is a package called `rxjs-compat` (install it with `npm install rxjs-compat`) which allows you to use RxJs 6+ with the old syntax.

However there are major performance and bundle size gains from using the newer syntax, because it supports Tree Shaking, so I would not recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very late response, but I got a similar error. For me even the Answer of @Daniel did not work. I had to use the pipe in a seperate statement:

```
...
this.currentUser = this.afAuth.authState;
this.currentUser.pipe(switchMap(user => {
    if (user) {
      // logged in, get custom user from Firestore
      return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges()
    } else {
      // logged out, null
      return of(null)
    }
}))
```

Alongside that, I encountered some troubles importing `switchmap`, `of` and `Observable`, but managed to get everything imported with:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import {switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

The code worked fine under

- Angular CLI: 7.3.8
- Node 10.15.3
- Angular 7.2.14
- rxjs: 6.5.1